# How to determine if NSLayoutConstraint is horizontal or vertical?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

This seems like it should be a simple task, but is there a way of telling programmatically if a `NSLayoutConstraint` is a horizontal or vertical constraint?

The only way I can think of to attempt making this difference is by calling `[constraint description];` and then searching the resulting string for `"V:"` or `"H:"`

The reason I want to find this information is I have 2 nearly identical constraints set on a `prototype` `UITableViewCell` on my `storyboard`, the only difference being one describes the horizontal distance from the `superview`, and the other the vertical. I want to remove the vertical, programmatically add constraints to describe a new view being added given a certain parameter being returned from my server.

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful!

## EDIT:

I accepted greymouser's answer because his explanation is a fantastic answer and is the way I ended up working around parsing the description, but also want to give credit to @kongtomorrow who also suggested this answer via twitter just before greymouser answered me here! Thanks for the help!

Here is the actual code I used to find the constraint:

```
NSArray *constraints = [bubble constraints];

for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in constraints) {
    if ([[constraint firstItem] isEqual:messageLabel] && [[constraint secondItem] isEqual:bubble] && [constraint secondAttribute] == NSLayoutAttributeTop) {
        [bubble removeConstraint:constraint];
    }
}
```

The above matches the firstItem, secondItem, and then secondAttribute of the constraint to confirm with reasonable certainty that I am looking at the right constraint, then I remove it and successfully add my new constraint-descriptions after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. `VFL` maps to the underlying `NSLayoutConstraint +:constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:` call.

However, if you check the firstAttribute or secondAttribute `NSLayoutAttribute` properties on the constraint, you may be able to deduce if it's horizontal or vertical. If you're generating your constraints from `VFL`, they're likely not intensely complex, so this may be a straightforward deduction For e.g., if you encounter an firstAttribute on the superview's set to `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` and the secondAttribute is `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` for a child view, then it's *likely* horizontal. But only likely.

You may just want to stick parsing the description, possibly subclassing `NSLayoutConstraint` to add a horizontal/vertical property, or maintaing ancillary data for each constraint in a dictionary that records H or V.

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically have to do this check for constraints pertaining to the views distance from its container, I think it's doable. Horizontal constraints would have first and second attribute either be `NSLayoutAttributeLeading` or `NSLayoutAttributeTrailing`, and Vertical constraints will have `NSLayoutAttributeTop` or `NSLayoutAttributeBottom`.

Also if these constraints are set using IB, you could actually create outlets for them.

Comment: This solution worked for me, although for horizontal NSLayoutAttributeCenterX should also be checked, and NSLayoutAttributeCenterY for vertical.